# Fail to send mail through send grid smtp.

Tags: laravel, amazon-ec2, sendgrid

I am using sendgrid for sending mail in laravel it work perfectly on my local and one aws ec2 instance.But it fail to send mail on another ec2 instance.I tried all the port like 2525,25,2587,587 using tls encryption.But nothing work for me.It give the following error

> Failed to authenticate on SMTP server with username "apikey" using 2 possible authenticators

Answer (score 2, accepted):

if your issue occurred in server that using https, you should change `MAIL_DRIVER to mail` and `MAIL_PORT to 465`

```
MAIL_DRIVER=mail
MAIL_HOST=smtp.sendgrid.net
MAIL_PORT=465
MAIL_USERNAME=yourusername
MAIL_PASSWORD=yourpassword
```

and on your **config/mail.php**

```
'encryption' => env('MAIL_ENCRYPTION', 'tls'),
```

change to

```
encryption' => 'ssl',
```

that's work for me.

Comment: My port was 587. When I changed it to 465 it worked. I didn't have to change the Mail Driver

Comment: If you will set driver as MAIL then it will send using phpmailer, not using SendGrid by SMTP